# How to get model with relation as hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I want a hash representation of my `Post` model with the posts's related comments included as an array of hashes.

My models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

So the output should be something like this:

```
{
  "id": 3,
  "body": "This is a post",
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "post_id": 3,
      "body": "This is a comment",
    }
  ]
}
```

Things I have tried (that would only return the post, but not its related comments:

```
Post.includes(:comments).as_json
Post.eager_load(:comments).as_json
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation for `as_json`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html). It's very well-documented and this exact topic is covered.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
Post.as_json(include: :comments)
```

Comment: This works, but it seems to make two SQL queries when all that's needed is one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that this is what ActiveRecord will do for you: 2 requests.
one for the parent object and one for the children objects.

Try creating the SQL code using a JOIN and direct it to an object and then run as_json on the resulting object.